# Stewart theorem validity on a sphere

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

EDIT1:

On a spherical surface radius $R$ a geodesic triangle is drawn:

Let a,b, and c be the lengths of the sides of the geodesic triangle. Let d be the geodesic arc length of a cevian to the side of length a. The cevian divides the side of length a into two geodesic arc segments of length m and n, with m adjacent to c and n adjacent to b.

Would a * spherical Stewart's theorem*

$${\displaystyle b^{2}m+c^{2}n=a(d^{2}+mn)}? $$

be still valid? I do not think so.

If not, what changes in the angles of spherical triangle be incorporated into a  new relation?

The radius of sphere is thrice the circum-diameter of a plane triangle with these dimensions.

Comment: Any reason to believe that can be generalized?

Comment: It is derived using cosine law in the plane. So spherical trigonometry is valid it appears. But wanted to find more applicable grounds...

Comment: @ ArcticChar  I have edited so that we might see how the relations  would change at least .on a spherical triangle.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\sin a \cos d = \sin m \cos b + \sin n \cos c$ for a spherical triangle. And by third-order approximation, we can recover the original Stewart theorem $a^3 + 3ad^2 = m^3 + 3mb^2 + n^3 + 3nc^2$.

Comment: K.Jeong, @Narasimham: Thanks for having pointed out the applicability of [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem). Please note my recent related question [_"Generalizing Stewart's theorem to timelike triangles in Lorentzian spaces of constant curvature"_ (mse/q/4029996)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029996/generalizing-stewarts-theorem-to-timelike-triangles-in-lorentzian-spaces-of-con)